# How do I buid a WCF Query on the fly?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity, wcf-data-services

I'd like to build some linq or alternatively, build a query string on the fly and pass it to a WCF Data Service (with Entity Framework data model).

Something like this:

```
 public List<DocumentInformationRecord> SearchClientDocs(string clientCode,
            string clientName, string contactName, string groupCode, string groupName,
            string filename, string createdby, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
 {
   List<DocumentInformationRecord> results = new List<DocumentInformationRecord>();
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientCode)) 
   //Add the client code clause...
```

etc..

```
var qry = from c in context.DocumentInformationRecord.where(dynamicQuery);

            //Etc......
```

Any ideas?  I tried the predicate builder (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) but got some invalid operation exceptions.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it will suit your situation, but you can use expression trees to build dynamic queries. There is a [good tutorial here](http://www.equivalence.co.uk/archives/tag/dynamic-linq-query)

Comment: I went down the route of building the Dataservice query with a built up string and the qry.AddQueryOption("$filter") method instead.  But expression trees are the best way, just for now it seemed quicker to go down the $filter option.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I entirely understand your question, but I have sometimes written code to build up LINQ queries with different parts depending on input. Typically that goes something like this:

```
var qry = from item in someList
          select item;

if (nameFilter != null)
{
    qry = qry.Where(item => item.Name == nameFilter);
}

if (someOtherFilter != null)
{
    qry = qry.Where(item => item.SomeOtherStuff == someOtherFilter);
}
// and so on
```

That way you can build the query step by step. You can do this because of *deferred execution*; the query will not be executed against the data source until you start iterating over the result.

Comment: This works well but not if the resulting query has to be a long combination of and's and or's that have to be built up at runtime.